# in-app payment with google wallet in chrome packaged app with license

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app, android-pay, chrome-web-store

I have a packaged app for chrome web store and I want to implement in-app payment. When a buyer will pay I want to provide a license for him(to use full functionality of my app). Thus, I want to check for the license every time the app starts. It seems that it should be very trivial task but I'm struggling with this task 4 days already. Documentation turned out to be VERY confusing. That's why I want to ask if it is possible at all? Is there any **complete** samples?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a complete sample:
https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/tree/master/samples/managed-in-app-payments

Basically, once you have an app/ext in the **Chrome Web Store Developer Dashboard** and a **Google Wallet Merchant** account connected, you

**1)** In the EDIT page of the app/ext in your dashboard, add the items to the "In-app products" tab (and make sure they are activated), and then

**2)** include the [buy.js](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/blob/master/samples/managed-in-app-payments/scripts/buy.js) JS file in your app/ext package.
To get a list of the items within your app/ext call getSkuDetails method and to initiate a buy, call the buy method.

**For more detailed explanation of the steps, see this page:**
https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/payments-iap

**3)** To check if your user has already purchased the item, call getPurchases and see if the item is still listed and is "ACTIVE".

Comment: I added more info about how to follow up and check everytime the app starts. Please let me know if you have any issues.